# Selenium's select first_selected_option has no 'value' attribute, how can I add this attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here are my code as below:

```
twoglink_rate_list = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('opmode'))
twoglink_rate_value = twoglink_rate_list.first_selected_option.value
```

I got an error from above code:

> [AttributeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'value']

If I change to

```
twoglink_rate_value = twoglink_rate_list.first_selected_option.text
```

I will get its text, but I want to get this option value not its text

where can I add 'value' attribute?

Answer (score 2):

`first_selected_option.value` you are trying to get the Python web element object value, which doesn't exists. You want to get the html web element value. You can use `get_attribute()` for that

```
twoglink_rate_value = twoglink_rate_list.first_selected_option.get_attribute('value')
```